# NGinx Block all Wordpress Files except wp-login and wp-admin

Tags: nginx, wordpress, deny

How can I `deny all;` access to all front-facing wordpress files, except `wp-login.php` and `wp-admin`?

What I currently have blocks access to all `wp-*` including the `wp-admin`

```
location ~ ^/(index\.php|wp-.*\.php) {
    deny all;
}
```

Tried Code Block:

```
# Deny Access to all of Wordpress Front End files except wp-login.php, wp-admin, and default.php
location ~* !^/(default.(.*)$)|!^/(wp-login.(.*)$)|!^/(wp-admin/) {
    deny all;
}
```

all are still accessible

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What problem are you having?

Comment: I want to block access to all wordpress front-end files with the exception of wp-admin and wp-login.php, but I don't know how to include the exceptions for wp-admin and wp-login.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin/install.php|wp-cron.php|foo.php|bar.txt|etc.foo) {
      rewrite ^ / permanent;
    }
```

Anyway. After a few experiences with the so called software Wordpress, I heavily recommend, using a read-only live-plattform, if possible.

Comment: Hey mate, actually...   that's what I'm building :)   I only want to use the admin side of wordpress for my site, but "need" to block all access to the WP front-end without getting rid of it (for updates to the backend)

Comment: I think I may be better off doing something like this: http://serverfault.com/questions/222854/set-nginx-conf-to-deny-all-connections-except-to-certain-files-or-directories